# Удалить цифры, указанные в строке, из массива

Tags: golang

Возможно ли решить такую задачу на языке go: я ввожу строку, к примеру, (sfew13nj24), программа должна ее проверить и убрать из массива с цифрами от 1 до 9 все цифры, которые были в строке, программа должна вывести (5 6 7 8 9).

Comment: Проблема в go или в алгоритме?

Comment: Проблема в алгоритме, так как я не могу из string сделать int, как, к примеру, в паскале командой  (Val).

Comment: В цикле проходим по строке (посимвольно), Если символ в диапазоне цифр (то есть выполняется условие вида `if a>='0' and a<='9'`, но перепишите его на go!), то значит это число, можно исключать. Для преобразования символа в число, можно использовать `strconv.Atoi(s)`. Хотя по факту это и не нужно. Можно сделать строку из всех цифр и удалять с нее символ.

Comment: Спасибо, с этим я разобрался, но возник другой вопрос.
 
    input, _ := strconv.Atoi(inputstr)

Что означат нижнее подчеркивание, никак не могу понять, но без него не работает.

Comment: >Что означат нижнее подчеркивание, никак не могу понять, но без него не работает.
В Go функции могут возвращать сразу несколько результатов. strconv.Atoi как раз из таких, она возвращает одновременно int и error.
Тобишь, к примеру 

    input, err := strconv.Atoi(inputstr)

положит в переменную input результат приведения к числу, а в err ошибку, если в процессе выполнения что-то пойдёт не так.
Если же вас какие-то переменные не интересуют, можете заменять их нижним прочерком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю, как насчет Go, вот решение на самом обычном С. Может быть, поможет...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int digits[9];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) { digits[i] = 1; }
    while ((i = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (i >= (int)'1' && i <= (int)'9')
        {
            digits[i - (int)'1'] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (digits[i]) { putchar(i + (int)'1'); }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

На C# я бы еще красивее сделал - через HashSet, но в новомодном языке Go... нет множеств. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177428/sets-data-structure-in-golang

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но программу я уже написал )

Comment: Кстати, если нужны еще задачи, рекомендую сайт http://CodeAbbey.com